# Custom environment with gnome-terminal

Tags: 14.04, command-line, bash, gnome-terminal

I tried to put this into the startup applications:

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory /media/Data/work/ -e '. .env/bin/activate'
```

where `.env/bin/activate` represents my virtualenv.

For some reason, it doesn't work; the terminal starts but displays a message

```
Failed to execute child process "." (Permission denied)
```

If I just start gnome-terminal manually, and then execute `.env/bin/activate`, everything works fine.

What am I doing wrong? (Running Ubuntu 14.04.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command instead:

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory /media/Data/work/ -x bash --rcfile .env/bin/activate
```

From `man bash`:

```
 The --rcfile file option will force bash to read and execute commands
 from file instead of /etc/bash.bashrc and ~/.bashrc.
```

Comment: That is a bit heavy-handed, isn't it? Ignoring `.bashrc`?

Comment: @muru This so far the only method I've found to keep 1. the terminal opened and 2. the virtual env activated. As ending the gnome-terminal command with an extra `bash` close/hide the venv.

Comment: @Muru: It'll be up to the OP to decide whether the cure is worse then the disease...  >:-)  (I've upvoted as I wouldn't have found this)

Comment: couldn't the desease be cured by doing 'source /etc/bash.bashrc' and 'source ~./bashrc' in the custom rc-file ?